# How to set Socket File Descriptor with FD_SET Unix in C / C++

Tags: c++, c, sockets, unix, select

I’m currently working on a socket programming project.
Let’s assume:

```
fd_set fd_in;
```

Now I would like to set the file Descriptor for the select function:

```
FD_SET(socket_fd, &fd_in);
```

Is that the right way ?

Then I use the select function:

```
int rc = select(socket_fd + 1, &fd_in, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Having done some research I haven’t managed to proceed.

I appreciate your support,
Regards, from Brooks

Comment: Have you tried at least what you propose? did it work?

Comment: @LuisColorado Hey, Yes I did, but I still face Issues ;(. Maybe that’s just because of some other functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate manual pages are available on line, for example [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fd_set).

Nevertheless, it might not be clear to you that before adding any file descriptors to your `fd_set`, you should first clear it:

```
FD_ZERO(&fd_in);
```

Then, yes, you use `FD_SET()` just as you present in the question:

> ```
> FD_SET(socket_fd, &fd_in);
> ```

That assumes that the value of `socket_fd` is an open file descriptor.

Having done so, it is reasonable to use a pointer to the resulting `fd_set` as one of the arguments to `select()`, again as you present:

> ```
> int rc = select(socket_fd + 1, &fd_in, NULL, NULL, NULL);
> ```

Do note that

- that particular call registers interest only in the specified file descriptor becoming available for reading (or for accepting a connection if it is a listening socket), not for writing or exceptional conditions.
- you must check `select()`'s return value and take appropriate action based on the result.  Since you're using only a single `fd_set` with a single element, without a timeout, you should expect `select` to return either 1 (when the file descriptor is ready) or -1 (on error).
- generally speaking, you need to set up the fd_set(s) each time you call `select`.  Except in certain special cases, the contents of the sets after `select()` returns are often not the same as they were before the call, and in the event that `select` reports an error then you cannot afterward rely on anything about them at all.  Thus, when `select()` is called in a loop, which is common, there generally needs to be fd_set setup code in the same loop.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your awesome tutorial ;)